# Describing a function partially in Z3 or Z3py

Tags: python, z3, z3py

This is my first question in Stackoverflow. So please do offer advice if I'm breaking any house rules.

I have started learning Z3Py only recently. I found myself in a situation where I know the following about an Int->Int function **A** that I want to describe and leave it for Z3Py to solve:

```
The summation of A(x) = 10000 where 0<x<100
A(x) > 10 where 0<x<100
A(x) = 0 where x>= 100
A(3) = 190
A(12) = 1200
```

How can these constraints be described in Z3Py (Or Z3)?

Comment: Never used this library but this [resource](https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html) from Stanford should help you out

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple ways to code this example in z3py. With the constraints as you listed, you can use a symbolic array, an uninterpreted function or use separate variables for each of the 100 elements.

### Using arrays

The simplest for this case would be the use of arrays: That is, model the `Int -> Int` function as an array:

```py
from z3 import *

A = Array('A', IntSort(), IntSort())

s = Solver()

total = 0
for i in range(100):
    s.add(A[i] > 10)
    total = total + A[i]

s.add(total == 10000)

s.add(A[ 3] ==  190)
s.add(A[12] == 1200)

k = Int('k')
s.add(ForAll(k, (Implies(Or(k < 0, k >= 100),  A[k] == 0))))

if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    for i in range(100):
        v = m.evaluate(A[i]).as_long()
        print("%3d: %d" % (i, v))
```

When run, this prints:

```
  0: 131
  1: 19
  2: 436
  3: 190
  4: 12
  5: 11
  6: 19
  7: 24
  8: 11
  9: 13
 10: 133
 11: 134
 12: 1200
 13: 39
 14: 132
 15: 134
 16: 134
 17: 134
 18: 30
 19: 132
 20: 132
 21: 38
 22: 16
 23: 132
 24: 22
 25: 132
 26: 134
 27: 27
 28: 134
 29: 76
 30: 130
 31: 15
 32: 132
 33: 134
 34: 31
 35: 123
 36: 35
 37: 58
 38: 123
 39: 64
 40: 49
 41: 20
 42: 139
 43: 24
 44: 134
 45: 11
 46: 132
 47: 132
 48: 22
 49: 11
 50: 134
 51: 134
 52: 134
 53: 132
 54: 132
 55: 11
 56: 134
 57: 11
 58: 11
 59: 132
 60: 11
 61: 71
 62: 134
 63: 58
 64: 132
 65: 132
 66: 134
 67: 134
 68: 39
 69: 74
 70: 132
 71: 134
 72: 134
 73: 11
 74: 18
 75: 134
 76: 16
 77: 132
 78: 17
 79: 132
 80: 132
 81: 132
 82: 15
 83: 132
 84: 132
 85: 134
 86: 15
 87: 132
 88: 134
 89: 18
 90: 132
 91: 132
 92: 132
 93: 132
 94: 12
 95: 132
 96: 22
 97: 121
 98: 24
 99: 11
```

You can sum up the values printed to ensure it indeed gives you `10000`.

### Using uninterpreted functions

You can also model `A` as an uninterpreted function. The changes required is really trivial to the above:

```py
from z3 import *

A = Function('A', IntSort(), IntSort())

s = Solver()

total = 0
for i in range(100):
    s.add(A(i) > 10)
    total = total + A(i)

s.add(total == 10000)

s.add(A( 3) ==  190)
s.add(A(12) == 1200)

k = Int('k')
s.add(ForAll(k, (Implies(Or(k < 0, k >= 100),  A(k) == 0))))

if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    for i in range(100):
        v = m.evaluate(A(i)).as_long()
        print("%3d: %d" % (i, v))
```

This prints:

```
  0: 11
  1: 11
  2: 11
  3: 190
  4: 11
  5: 11
  6: 11
  7: 11
  8: 11
  9: 11
 10: 11
 11: 11
 12: 1200
 13: 11
 14: 11
 15: 11
 16: 11
 17: 11
 18: 11
 19: 11
 20: 11
 21: 11
 22: 11
 23: 11
 24: 11
 25: 11
 26: 11
 27: 11
 28: 11
 29: 11
 30: 11
 31: 11
 32: 11
 33: 11
 34: 11
 35: 11
 36: 11
 37: 11
 38: 11
 39: 11
 40: 11
 41: 11
 42: 11
 43: 11
 44: 11
 45: 11
 46: 11
 47: 11
 48: 11
 49: 11
 50: 11
 51: 11
 52: 11
 53: 11
 54: 11
 55: 11
 56: 11
 57: 11
 58: 11
 59: 11
 60: 11
 61: 11
 62: 11
 63: 11
 64: 11
 65: 11
 66: 11
 67: 11
 68: 11
 69: 11
 70: 11
 71: 11
 72: 11
 73: 11
 74: 7543
 75: 11
 76: 11
 77: 11
 78: 11
 79: 11
 80: 11
 81: 11
 82: 11
 83: 11
 84: 11
 85: 11
 86: 11
 87: 11
 88: 11
 89: 11
 90: 11
 91: 11
 92: 11
 93: 11
 94: 11
 95: 11
 96: 11
 97: 11
 98: 11
 99: 11
```

The model is quite different in this case, but it's easy to see that it has `A(3) = 190`, `A(12) = 1200`, `A(74) = 7543`, and all other entries are set to 11; giving you a total of `190 + 1200 + 7543 + 11 * 97 = 10000`.

### Using separate variables

Yet a third method would be to allocate 100 integer elements in a python array, and assert the constraints on individual elements separately. This would lead to the simplest model, as it would not use any quantification. Of course, this would model the fact that elements outside the range `0..99` are 0 implicitly, so only use this if this constraint does not need to be explicitly mentioned. Again, the coding is almost identical:

```py
from z3 import *

A = [Int('A_%d' % i) for i in range(100)]

s = Solver()

total = 0
for i in range(100):
    s.add(A[i] > 10)
    total = total + A[i]

s.add(total == 10000)

s.add(A[ 3] ==  190)
s.add(A[12] == 1200)

if s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    for i in range(100):
        v = m.evaluate(A[i]).as_long()
        print("%3d: %d" % (i, v))
```

I'm eliding the output of this for brevity. Note how we're using `A` as a python list in this case, instead of a symbolic array directly supported by z3py itself.

### Summary

At the end of the day, the constraints you've described are simple enough that it can use all these three techniques. Which one is the best depends on what other constraints you'd want to model. (In particular, you'd want to avoid anything that makes heavy use of quantifiers, like `ForAll` above since SMT solvers don't do all that well for quantifiers in general. This problem is simple enough so it doesn't pose an issue, but when your constraints get complicated, it can increase solving times or lead the solver to answer `unknown`.)

Hope this gets you started. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer. is total in your answer treated as a free/dummy variable because you did not define it as a variable in the system of constraints? If this is the case, how is it represented/internally?

Comment: `total` is not a variable. It's an expression that you build as you go along. This is the advantage of using the high-level interface (like Python, C, C++, Haskell etc. bindings to z3) as opposed to direct SMTLib level programming, as it allows you to programmatically build expressions, allowing you to express bounded loops easily. (There's no way to write a loop directly in SMTLib.)

Comment: You can put `print(s.sexpr())` right before the call to `s.check()`, and you'll see the SMTLib this Python program generates. That might be illuminating for you.

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find a straight-forward SMT encoding of your problem, *except* for the summation requirement.

```
(set-option :smt.mbqi true) ; also try false (e-matching instead of MBQI)

(declare-fun A (Int) Int)

(assert 
  (=
    10000
    (+ 
      (A 1)
      (A 2)
      (A 3)
      ; ...
      (A 99))))

; A(x) > 10 where 0<x<100
(assert (forall ((x Int))
  (implies
    (and (< 0 x) (< x 100))
    (> (A x) 10))))

; A(x) = 0 where x>= 100
(assert (forall ((x Int))
  (implies
    (>= x 100)
    (> (A x) 10))))

; A(3) = 190
(assert (= (A 3) 190))

; A(12) = 1200
(assert (= (A 12) 1200))

(check-sat)
```

A few remarks:

- All SMT functions are total; if you want to encode a partial function, you'll have to explicitly model the function's domain, and make definitional axioms conditional on whether or not an argument is in the domain. Z3 will still give you a total model for the function, though.
- Arbitrary summation is non-trivial to encode in SMT, since there is no sum comprehension operator. Your case is simpler, though, since your sum ranges over a statically known number of elements (*0 < x < 100*).
- I'd not be surprised if Z3py offers a convenient source syntax to generate sums over statically-known many elements

Comment: Thanks Malte your code and comments were absolutely valuable for someone who is still feeling his way into SOLVER-land like myself. Is there a shorthand way to write a summation? Or at least is there a way to write a macro to do that? Thanks

Comment: Another question. x in the forall statement is a dummy/free variable, isn't it? If this is the case, how did Z3 decide how to treat x? Also, is there an explicit way to tell Z3 that a certain variable is a dummy variable?

Comment: @HakeemGadi `x` is bound by the universal quantifier, it is not a free variable. Depending on how Z3 is configured, it may either use e-matching or MBQI to handle quantifiers: https://www.rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h28.